# Regex pattern to not to include zeros

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match a pattern for validation . I want to match a decimal number where numeric part can have upto 14 digits including + or - without 0 and after decimal has upto 4 digits. Valid patterns are :

```
+1.23
9857.6543
-745290.0
```

Invalid patterns are:

```
 0
 0.00
 1.23456
```

I have tried `^[0-9]{0,14}\.[0-9]{0,4}$`.
I am not getting how to match for `+`,`-` and `0` condition

Comment: Is `12.` or `12` valid?

Comment: and how about `0.0`, `1.0`, `1.00`

Comment: 12. is invalid , 12 is valid , 0.0 is invalid, 1.0 is valid, 1.00 is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work `^(\+|-)?(([1-9]|0(?=0*[1-9]))[0-9]{0,13}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?|0{1,14}\.(?=0*[1-9])[0-9]{1,4})$`

- `^(\+|-)?` - starts with +/-
- `(`
- `([1-9]|0(?=0*[1-9]))[0-9]{0,13}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?` - absolute value >= 1
- `|` - or
- `0{1,14}\.(?=0*[1-9])[0-9]{1,4}` - 0.**** with at least 1 non-zero digit
- `)`
- `$` - end

```js
const testcases = [
    '+1.23', 
    '9857.6543', 
    '-745290.0', 
    '1.0', 
    '1.00', 
    '12', 
    '0.01', 
    '+001.01', 
    '0', 
    '0.00', 
    '1.23456', 
    '0.0', 
    '12.'];
 
const regex = /^(\+|-)?(([1-9]|0(?=0*[1-9]))[0-9]{0,13}(\.[0-9]{1,4})?|0{1,14}\.(?=0*[1-9])[0-9]{1,4})$/;

testcases.forEach(n => console.log(`${n}\t - ${regex.test(n)}`));
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: `^[+-]?[1-9][0-9]{0,13}\.[0-9]{1,4}$`

---

`^` - start of string

`[+-]?` optionally, one between `+` and `-`

`[1-9][0-9]{0,13}` - a 14 digit number that doesn't start with 0

`\.` - decimal separator, has to be escaped or it will mean "any one character"

`[0-9]{1,4}` - up to 4 decimal digits

`$` - end of string

Comment: I agree on the character class, thanks for pointing it out. Given their third valid example, I assumed that zeros are allowed as long as the entire integer part isn't 0

Answer (score 1):

The pattern:

```
^[+-]?[^\D0]\d{0,13}\.\d{1,4}(?!\d)
```

matches the first 3 but not the second 3. `[^\D0]` is, if I'm not mistaken, strictly the same as `[123456789]`, but slightly more compact.

Answer (score 1):

You can assert that the string does not start with 1 or more zeroes, followed by an optional dot and optional zeroes.

Then match 1-14 digits and optionally a dot and 1-4 digits, which would also allow for `00001` for example

```
^(?!0+\.?0*$)[+-]?\d{1,14}(?:\.\d{1,4})?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!0+\.?0*$)` Negative lookahead, assert not 1+ zeroes, optional dot and optional zeroes
- `[+-]?` Optionally match `+` or `-`
- `\d{1,14}` Match 1-14 digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,4})?` Optionally match `.` and 1-4 digits
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZKCjXl/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
^(?!0\.?0*$)[\+\-]?[0-9]{1,14}\.?[0-9]{0,4}$
```

Note: this does not match decimals without a leading 0 like `.123` and does not match numbers with spaces in between the + or -. Though, these could be added to the pattern.

Requiring a non-zero digit before a `.` eliminates fractions of whole numbers, like 0.123.

Also, if you **don't** want integers and only want decimals, you will need to modify to make the `.` required:

```
^(?!0\.?0*$)[\+\-]?[0-9]{1,14}\.[0-9]{0,4}$
```